# Sphere rolling up a ramp

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

In this question, I did energy conservation, with the states being the initial one and the one where it is at the top , and I got

$$ .5 I w^2 + .5 mv^2 = mgh$$

However, in  the answer key they have done,

$$ .5 mv^2 + .5 Iw^2 = .5 Iw^2 + mgh$$

Now why would the k.e be turned to p.e but not the rolling energy??

Comment: I think there should be equality in textbook solution. Also the ball won't pure roll .It will stop pure rolling as soon as it climbs up that ramp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer key is right as there is no opposing torque to slow down the sphere.It will only loose it's translation KE.

It will loose it's translation KE due to gravity.
Gravitational force doesn't produce any torque as it passes through the center of the sphere.

You would have been right if friction would have been present on the ramp.
Then what happens is that v decreases due gravitational force , but as ball is pure rolling , frictional force decreases $\omega$ gradually just to ensure the ball is pure rolling .So  all it's KE is converted into Potential energy.(Provided there is sufficient height )

Now if you are wondering why won't i consider work done by friction?

The answer is because friction is static.There is no relative motion between point of contact of spehere and ground.

Comment: What does it mean physically? Does it keep perpetually rotating at the top?

Comment: Yes at one point only if all of the Translation  KE is converted  to PE.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, question states that surface is frictionless, it is not possible to translate rotation into potential without friction, so actually you only have kinetics energy and not rolling energy, assuming there's friction your equation is correct